# C# 7 string interpolation after reading string from database

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I have a string coming from database.

```
var query = @"Select SKUs from dbo.Order order by OrderDate OFFSET {skip} ROWS FETCH NEXT {take} ROWS ONLY"
```

This string is coming from database directly, so I dont have this string formed in code.
I want to use $ interpolation to replace them

```
var skip = 0;
var take = 200;
query = $query
```

Is there any way I can do this? I know I can use replace or string.format but just curious if we can do this.

Comment: Why not use a parameterized query and eliminate any possibility of errors or SQL injection?

Comment: Echoing @PanagiotisKanavos, reading a query (ie "code") from an external source then executing it is a very dangerous idea.

Answer (score 2):

The `$""` syntax is only for string *literals*.

> The $ special character identifies a string literal as an interpolated string. An interpolated string is a string literal that might contain interpolation expressions.
>
> [$ - string interpolation (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

String literals only exist in the source code. Anything you read from a database is a string object and cannot be a literal.

As you mentioned, you need to use conventional methods to manipulate the string's data (string.Format, regex, etc).

Comment: As if you would have placed {0}, {1} in database we could have use string.format without  having string formed in code

Comment: @Manjay_TBAG what you ask is a bad idea in the first place. It leaves you open to SQL injections or simple coding errors. Don't construct SQL queries from strings (that includes string formatting) if possible

Comment: @Manjay_TBAG as for `without having string formed in code` but that's exactly what you're doing. String interpolation is still string construction in code. If `take` contained `1 ROWS ONLY; DROP TABLE Students;--` you'd end up with a query that dropped a table